# Printing a sorted list doesn't work fully, how can I fix this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code that I've written:

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
listObjects = []
listNames = []
listPressups = []
listPullups = []
sortedListPressups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = splitting[1]
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups.append(press_ups)
    sortedListPressups = sorted(listPressups, reverse = True)
print(sortedListPressups)
```

Outcome:

```
['8', '75', '74', '73', '67', '66', '58', '45', '33', '30', '25', '10']
```

Desired Outcome:

```
['75', '74', '73', '67', '66', '58', '45', '33', '30', '25', '10','8']
```

What have I done wrong?

Edit: This is the text file:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can share how `gymclub.txt` look like to make the others reproduce your case.

Comment: strings are sorted lexicographically (i.e. alphabetically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting is currently done lexicographically since the elements are strings. To have them formatted as per numbers, you have to convert them into numbers. You can do it as follows for any list

```
arr = ['8', '75', '74', '73', '67', '66', '58', '45', '33', '30', '25', '10']
print(sorted(list(map(int,arr)),reverse=True))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[75, 74, 73, 67, 66, 58, 45, 33, 30, 25, 10, 8]
```

---

So, in your case, you could do it as follows

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
listObjects = []
listNames = []
listPressups = []
listPullups = []
sortedListPressups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = splitting[1]
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups.append(press_ups)
    sortedListPressups = (sorted(list(map(int,listPressups)),reverse=True))
print(sortedListPressups)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[75, 74, 73, 67, 66, 58, 45, 33, 30, 25, 10, 8]
```

---

If you want the final list to be a list of strings itself as it originally was, then you could also do it in the following manner

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
listObjects = []
listNames = []
listPressups = []
listPullups = []
sortedListPressups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = splitting[1]
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups.append(press_ups)
    sortedListPressups = sorted(listPressups, reverse = True, key = int)
print(sortedListPressups)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['75', '74', '73', '67', '66', '58', '45', '33', '30', '25', '10','8']
```

---

You could also do `sortedListPressups.sort(reverse = True, key = int)` instead of using `sorted()` if you are going to sort in place . You can read more about these methods [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting strings, not numbers.

```py
>>> '8' > '75'
True
```

If you want to sort these elements according to their integer value, you could pass the `key` argument when sorting. This keeps the original array unchanged.

```py
>>> sorted(listPressups, key=int, reverse=True)
['75', '74', '73', '67', '66', '58', '45', '33', '30', '25', '10', '8']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the lines your read from strings to integers. Right now `sorted` sorts the strings in the list in lexicographic order.

```py
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
listObjects = []
listNames = []
listPressups = []
listPullups = []
sortedListPressups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = splitting[1]
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups.append(int(press_ups))

listPressups.sort(reverse=True)
print(listPressups)
```

1. I've taken the sort out of the loop for you. There is no need to sort the whole list every single iteration.
2. I've also used `list.sort()` instead of `sorted` to sort the list in place.

---

If you do want to preserve the behavior in which the items in the list are strings, you can use the `key` parameter and provide it with a function to sort by:

```
listPressups.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting characters leads to this outcome. You need to cast string elements to numbers:

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
listObjects = []
listNames = []
listPressups = []
listPullups = []
sortedListPressups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = int(splitting[1])
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups.append(press_ups)
    sortedListPressups = sorted(listPressups, reverse = True)
print(sortedListPressups)
```